# "Insecure Login Blocked: .Try re-loading the page as https:// "

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, https, facebook-login

I am trying to login with facebook in laravel framework. I have a app in https://developers.facebook.com/ and I used in my project.I am working with http://localhost:8000/ and I added Privacy Policy URL and I added cert in my system.
 When I run the project ,I get the following error ;

Warning
Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

How can fix this?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. It even gives you the answer: _"You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"_ - Specifically the last sentence.

Comment: how can I re-load the page as https://  ?

Comment: You need to set up your web server to use https (install certificate etc) for localhost. How that is done depends on your web server.

Answer (score 4):

It means that you are running on http://localhost:8000. Instead you need to be using https://localhost:8000

It still might fail however, because the certificate won't be validated by a third party authoriser.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
I will still be able to use HTTP with “localhost” addresses, but only while my app is still in development mode.